# Laravel Excel - Select columns to export

Tags: laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

I'm using Laravel Excel from maatwebsite but i have a problem with export data to xls file. I have this query but i don't need to show all columns in the xls file but i need to select all this columns to do operations before download the file. In my select i have 8 columns but in my headers i just have 7 to show but this doesn't work because the 8ª column appears too.

MY FUNCTION:

```
 public function toExcel($id) { $b = Budget::find($id);

$budget = Budget_Item::join('budgets', 'budget__items.id_budget', '=', 'budgets.id')
    ->join('items_sizes', 'budget__items.id_itemSize', '=', 'items_sizes.id')
    ->join('items', 'items_sizes.id_item', '=', 'items.id')
    ->join('material_types', 'items_sizes.id_materialType', '=', 'material_types.id')
    ->select('items.reference AS Referência', 'items.name AS Descrição', 'items_sizes.size AS Tamanho', 'material_types.material_type AS Material', 'budget__items.amount AS Quantidade', 'items_sizes.unit_price AS Val.Unitário', 'budget__items.price AS Val.Total', 'budget__items.purchasePrice')
    ->where('id_budget', '=', $id)
    ->get();

$budgetUpdate = [];
$budgetUpdate[] = ['Referência', 'Descrição', 'Tamanho', 'Material', 'Quantidade', 'Val.Unitário', 'Val.Total'];
foreach ($budget as $key)
{
  if ($key->purchasePrice > 0)
  {
    $key->unit_price = $key->purchasePrice;
  }

  $budgetUpdated[] = $key->toArray();
}
Excel::create('Proposta_'.$b->reference, function($excel) use($budgetUpdated)
{
  // Set the title
  $excel->setTitle('Proposta');

  $excel->sheet('Sheetname', function($sheet) use($budgetUpdated)
  {
    $sheet->fromArray($budgetUpdated, null, 'A1', false, true);
  });

})->download('xls');}
```

How can i solve that?

Thank's

Comment: I did the unset of column that i don't want but might have a solution with the excel api... but with unset works fine.

Answer (score 6):

**Tested on Laravel excel 3.1** [docs](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/collection.html)

**on controller**

```
public function exportAsCsv() 
{
    return Excel::download(new MyExport, 'invoices.xlsx');
}
```

**on MyExport, look at the map function**

```
 class MyExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, WithMapping{

    public function collection(){
           return MyTable:all();
    }

    // here you select the row that you want in the file
    public function map($row): array{
           $fields = [
              $row->myfield2,
              $row->myfield1,
         ];
        return fields;
    }
}
```

also check [this](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/nova/1.0/exports/customizations.html#concerns)

Comment: How to put numbers for the first column?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: I need number 1,2,3,4,5 for the first column. what should i do?

Answer (score 2):

For what its worth I ran into a similar issue and didnt find much in terms of a fix so heres my solution. 
1. I query the DB in the callback and get all the data I need. 
2. I then go over the collection and create a new array on each iteration and assign a value & header. Works great for picking out columns from a model

```
Excel::create('User List Export', function($excel) {
        $excel->sheet('Users', function($sheet) {
            $email = yourModelGoesHere::all();
            foreach ($email as $key => $value) {
                $payload[] = array('email' => $value['email'], 'name' => $value['name']);
            }
            $sheet->fromArray($payload);
        });
    })->download('xls');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way. 
$user_id = Auth::user()->id

```
Excel::create('User', function($excel) use ($user_id){ 
  $excel->sheet('Sheet', function($sheet) use($user_id){

     $user = User::where('user_id', $user_id)->select('name', 'email', 'role', 'address')->get();   
  });
})->export('xls');

return redirect('your route');
```